# Get data between two date on MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, between

How can I get the values between two dates.

I want to get the values between 2010-01-02 and 2010-01-04.

Example:

```
Value DateTime
A     2010-01-01 14:55:12
B     2010-01-02 14:55:12
C     2010-01-03 14:55:12
D     2010-01-04 14:55:12
E     2010-01-05 14:55:12
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

[expr BETWEEN min AND max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

> If expr is greater than or equal to
>   min and expr is less than or equal to
>   max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it
>   returns 0.

/

> For best results when using BETWEEN
>   with date or time values, you should
>   use CAST() to explicitly convert the
>   values to the desired data type.
>   Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to
>   two DATE values, convert the DATE
>   values to DATETIME values. If you use
>   a string constant such as '2001-1-1'
>   in a comparison to a DATE, cast the
>   string to a DATE.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer has already been accepted, but I thought I'd add a bit more to what @astander has mentioned. I answered a post recently regarding date queries, and a useful way of extracting more useful information from the dates using a date dimension.

See the following StackOverflow question, and look to my answer...

[Select all months within given date span, including the ones with 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093924/select-all-months-within-given-date-span-including-the-ones-with-0-values)