# mysql between dates getting the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have this following rows in mytable

```
date_start
-----------
2011-09-20 13:00:00
2011-10-01 13:14:00
2011-10-09 13:16:00
2011-09-27 15:00:00
2011-09-30 14:04:00
2011-10-03 14:00:00
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT date_start
FROM `mytable`
WHERE date_start >= "2011-09-19"
AND date_start <= "2011-09-30"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The problem here is it only outputs:

```
2011-09-20 13:00:00
2011-09-27 15:00:00
```

I expect this result:

```
    2011-09-20 13:00:00
    2011-09-27 15:00:00
    2011-09-30 14:04:00
```

Because if we look at the query it should include this as the result: `2011-09-30 14:04:00`

What am I doing wrong in here?

I also used the `BETWEEN` in mysql but the output is still the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of column is your `date_start` column? If it's a string type, the comparison you're doing is going to be a string comparison, in which case `"2011-09-30 14:04:00"` is considered to be 'greater than' `"2011-09-30"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A date treated as a datetime is assumed to have a 00:00:00 hours:minutes:seconds part. Thus, 2011-09-30 14:04:00 is in fact >= 2011-09-30.

To do what you want, try:

```
SELECT date_start
FROM `mytable`
WHERE date(date_start) >= "2011-09-19"
AND date(date_start) <= "2011-09-30"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This will work, but as the table becomes very large, the query will become very slow. MySQL will not be able to use any index you may have defined against the `start_date` field, as you are performing a function on the field. To effectively use an index, the field must be used in its raw state, and be compared with a non-deterministic value (something which doesn't relate to another part of the data)

Comment: Thus, use the `DATE()` function on the value being compared to, then add 1 day and use  `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

Time is also considered. you should mention this like

```
SELECT date_start
FROM `mytable`
WHERE date_start >= "2011-09-19"
AND date_start <= "2011-09-30 23:59:59"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

`2011-09-30` will be interpreted as `2011-09-30 00:00:00`. Try setting the end of the range as `2011-09-30 23:59:59` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would split the date and time elements into two separate fields, `date_start` and `time_start`, which would then enable your query to work correctly as coded, and also allow you to do more complicated and interesting date related activities such as are explained on my answer to the following question.

[Select all months within given date span, including the ones with 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093924/select-all-months-within-given-date-span-including-the-ones-with-0-values)

If however you can't change much about the way the system works, adding a single day to the date you wish to filter by, and then doing a `<` instead of an `<=` comparison would also work.

```
WHERE date_start >= "2011-09-19"
    AND date_start < "2011-10-01"
```

This will work faster than performing a DATE(date_start) within your filter, as MySQL will be unable to use any indexes as you are performing a function on the fields that could be indexed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`date_start <= '2011-09-30'` implies that the date `2011-09-30 00:00:00` is included but `2011-09-30 00:00:01` and later are not. You can use the `<` operator plus come commonsense date arithmetic for a workaround:

```
SELECT date_start
FROM   mytable
WHERE  date_start >= '2011-09-19'
AND    date_start <  '2011-09-30' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
LIMIT  0, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **between** statement in query then it will retrieve all the records  which are in between starting and endpoints.

For example:

```
SELECT date_start
FROM `mytable`
WHERE date_start between '2011-09-19'and '2011-09-30:23:59:59'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Just try this as per your requirement.