# Retrieve records from MySQL database using only today's Day and Month in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a service on a website where events in history are displayed depending on the dat their viewed. So if you go on the site on the 1st January, it will only display events that happened on that date.

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $onthisday = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT otd.thedate, otd.title, otd.content
            FROM ShoutMainBundle:Onthisday otd
            WHERE otd.thedate = CURRENT_DATE()
            ORDER BY otd.id DESC'
        );

    $otd = $onthisday->getResult();
```

The problem with this is that as it uses `CURRENT_DATE()`, it will only return results that match todays day, month and year.

What I'm trying to do is only retrieve records using todays day and month, and ignore the year.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
I've now used this code:

```
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Which gives the following error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 100: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'DAY'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your table, filtering against the day and month like this won't be very quick, as there will not be an index that will satisfy the query very well.

What you can do is use a "Date Dimension" table and join to it based on the date within your data. Then, if you filter against that table based on the day and month, you will return a single record for each year from within the dimension table, and that will then join through to your main data table and pull all the information you need in a relatively efficient manor.

See my answer to the following question for an explanation of the date dimension table...

[Select all months within given date span, including the ones with 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093924/select-all-months-within-given-date-span-including-the-ones-with-0-values)

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `createNativeQuery` function instead of `createQuery`

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-native-queries

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MySQL `DAY()` and `MONTH()` functions to extract the date and the month parts alone from the given date.

```
WHERE DAY(otd.thedate) = DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(otd.thedate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

For the list of functions take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: This gives an error with Doctrine. I've put the error in the above edit.

Comment: See above, I've made the change.

Comment: @mickburkejnr try `DAYOFMONTH()` instead of `DAY()`