# How to find data between two different dates?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to find data between two dates and display results in table.

Below is the code which doesn't work.

```
ps = DbConnection.cn.prepareStatement("SELECT Bill_no, Date, Cust_Name, Contact_No, Reg_No, Model, CC, QTY, Engine_No, Chasis_No, Payment_Mode, Grand_Total  FROM stock WHERE date = '$from' and '$to' ");
```

Comment: `date between '$from' and '$to' `

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get data between two date on MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716336/get-data-between-two-date-on-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `between` operator:

```
SELECT Bill_no, Date, Cust_Name, Contact_No, Reg_No, Model, CC, QTY, Engine_No, Chasis_No, Payment_Mode, Grand_Total  
FROM   stock 
WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

Mandatory comment:
Using string replacements leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should really consider using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like `to`, you have to use `between`

```
           WHERE date between '$from' and '$to'
```